URL is replacing with special characters python
This is my URL: https://10.10.10.20/v1/device[]=1_2234.
When I send the URL in my Python scripts, it's replacing the [] with %5B and %5D.
import requests

url = 'https://10.10.10.20/v1/device[]=1_2234'
response = requests.get(api_key,  url)
print(response)

Error:
requests.exceptions.HTTPError: 404 Client Error: Not Found for url: https://10.10.10.20/v1/device%5B%5D=1_2234

requests.get(api_key,  url) I don't see how this code even runs, because api_key is undefined, and surely url is supposed to be the first argument?

Is this what you want to ask? What do % signs mean in a url?
